# What are the different ways in which musical instruments are grouped together?

Tags: instruments

There are of course several ways to organize different kinds of musical instruments, but I wonder what strategies are used by different traditions, especially ethnomusicologists who probably need criteria to classify a wider array of instruments.

Thanks!

Comment: I've just added a new answer to the linked duplicate question, which specifically refers to ethnomusicologists, and provides the name (Hornbostel-Sachs) for the previously-described classification system.